# localhost on WAMP gives "Unable to connect"

Tags: windows-xp, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I have installed `WAMP (Version 2.2 32 bit) on Windows XP SP 3`. After installation, I get a **"Unable to connect"** message when I open `localhost on Firefox`.

Could someone point me to the direction of resolving this.

Comment: have you tried this  http://localhost:8080

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan Yes, I have tried changing port to 8080

Comment: check your wamp icon in tray, are apache and mysql started successfully

Comment: I later discovered that Apache hasn't started properly, although I don't understand why. I did setup WAMP many times before now (though few years has passed) and it was so self guiding, I did not have to do any tweaking. Not sure how I can resole the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is perhaps too localized. Since I was trying it on Windowx XP Service Pack 3, and most new applications are probably giving up comprehensive support for Windows XP as its support is about to be dropped by Microsoft itself. A solution to the problem may not eventually exist.

I tried XAMPP and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also checked your HOSTS file

> C:/windows/systems32/drivers/etc/hosts

It should have this line in it ( not commented )

> 127.0.0.1 localhost

If you see this line, without a comment

> ::1 localhost

either comment it out (add a # in col1) or remove it completely.

This is a **IPV6** version of localhost and is not really required yet, but MS decided to be ready for **IPV6** and add it to the hosts file.

Comment: Nothing as such in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your WAMP Server might be offline. So,click on the Wamp icon in System tray and select 'Put Online'. Hope that ll resolve the problem .

Comment: it's not offline, it's online